# How to delete all cookies with the same name?

Tags: php, cookies

I got 3 cookies with the same name on my website.
http://clip2net.com/s/jm4CcZ
They got different paths ('/', '/call', '/call/login') and different domains ('.domain.com', 'domain.com').
Now I use several setcookie() instuctions to delete each of them.

Is there more smart way to delete them at once?

Comment: duplicate question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506702/how-to-delete-the-same-cookie-in-php-from-two-different-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not all at once. If you want remove the specific cookies you need to use the cookie name. If you want to unset all cookies you can use this:

```
// unset cookies
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
```

This is a function that is published on http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#Hcom73484

Comment: Thanks.
Why the cookies with the same name are not being rewrited?

Comment: You said the cookies are on a different domain. Cookies are domain related so you can have same cookie names for different (sub)domains. Note that my solution works for the cookies of one domain and cannot delete cookies of multiple domains (for the reason that cookies are domain related)

Comment: yes I know about policy, but '.domain.com' & 'domain.com' are the same domains, isn't it?

Comment: No, '.domain.com' is an subdomain of 'domain.com'. So if you create an cookie on the subdomain '.domain.com' it will be only available on that specific subdomain.